# Django project name

Tags: django, structure

My question is rather difficult to wrap in words, but let's try:

I reckon it's easier to explain my problem with a chart demonstrating my django project structure:

Project1 -------- /Project1

```
                        settings.py
                        urls.py
                        models.py
                        views.py
            manage.py

            /App1
                        urls.py
                        models.py
                        views.py
```

Now, in my views.py in App1, how could I do "project1.models import *" without hard coding "project1"? Instead, I would need to have a dynamic name of the main project (project1 in this case).

My goal is that I could use this same structure also in my next project with as little changes in the code as possible. In this case, at the moment I would need to change that one line in my App1 views to whatever is the name of my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have models and views in your project directory?

Comment: Views for no reason (just copy/pasted the example from another folder) but models for I want to have everything site related in that one place. Like the different pages of this particular site, or the content for these pages. Other parts of the site (menu, gallery etc.) are all seperate apps, which only fetch the actual content from the main models. They work with any project, given that the content is available. so in theory this works by only changing the Project1 to another site. Apps can then be enabled or disabled if needed - but the site and it's content are in that main folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from ..models import *
```

Comment: Wow, that easy? I'm a bit worried now; If something sounds too easy to be true, it most likely is. Especially in programming... I'll give it go as soon as I get back to my code, cheers!